# %^% operator from expm package doesn't recognize sparse matrices

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, exponential

I'm using the `%^%` operator from `expm` package to calculate the power of a sparse matrix like below:

```
# Convert to sparse
Qm <- Matrix(Qm, sparse = TRUE)
# Calculate the power
Qmp <- expm::`%^%`( Qm, as.numeric(L)-1 )
```

the `class(Qm)` returns `Matrix` but I'm getting the following error:

> Error in expm::`%^%`(Qm, as.numeric(L) - 1) : not a matrix

Is this due to an incompatibility of `%^%` operator with `Matrix` objects or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If there are no methods for sparse matrices defined, you can't use the function with sparse matrices. R is case sensitive, a Matrix is not a matrix.

Comment: So you are telling that `expm` doesn't work with sparse matrices? If yes, is there any alternative way to calculate the power of a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation clearly says that only class `matrix` is accepted as input. You have two options:

```
Qm <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1), 2) 

library(Matrix)
Qm <- Matrix(Qm, sparse = TRUE)

library(expm)
Qm %^% 3
#Error in Qm %^% 3 : not a matrix

#coerce to dense matrix
as.matrix(Qm) %^% 3
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    2    3

#or use loop
Res <- Qm
for (i in seq_len(3-1)) Res <- Res %*% Qm
#2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#
#[1,] 1 2
#[2,] 2 3
```